# Do I need to give my snake plants a snip after a fall

Tags: indoors, snake-plants

My daughter dropped my snake plant from the stand could someone please guide me of where to now, I think it is little damaged? Snapped leaves but not fully broken (will post pic if I can) But could it get worse if I just leave it..? Would it be better to trim the broken leaves?

Comment: How do I add pic please

Comment: Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar button and the image button. This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Edit] your post and look for the "sun and mountains" icon along the top.